# The argument of -i should be 2 readable file

Tags: python, argparse

I am currently using argparse like this:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def is_valid_file(parser, arg):
    if not os.path.exists(arg):
        parser.error("File %s khong ton tai!" % arg)
    else:
        return open(arg, 'rb')   # return an open file handle

def readinput():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="ikjMatrix multiplication")
    parser.add_argument("-i", dest="filename", required=True,
                        help="File need predict", metavar="FILE",
                        type=lambda x: is_valid_file(parser, x))
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.filename.read()
```

I want to run  python3 demo.py -i text1.txt text2.txt.

I would like to get 2 readable file. How can I do that?

thank you for your help!

Comment: Named arguments (like `-i`) come with at most one value. You command line example has one named and one positional argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Testfile")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--files", help="The files", nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.files)
```

Usage:

```
python .\test.py -f 1.txt 2.txt
['1.txt', '2.txt']

python .\test.py -f 1.txt      
usage: test.py [-h] [-f FILES FILES]
test.py: error: argument -f/--files: expected 2 arguments
```